# How to correctly import Gson to Maven based JavaFX project in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, javafx, gson

I am working on a simple JavaFX (FXML) application that uses external API in JSON format. I wanted to use GSON. I've already added Library from Maven (Project Structure -> Libraries -> + -> From Maven -> Maven: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5). Also added the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

My module-info file:

```
module com.example.democtc {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.net.http;
    requires com.google.gson;
    opens com.example.democtc to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.democtc;
}
```

The one and only problem visible is

```
"Module 'com.example.democtc' reads package 'javafx.beans' from both 'javafx.base' and 'javafx.base'"
```

in module-info file. Intellij doesn't see any problem during writing phase (no errors of non-existing modules in imports etc.), but when trying to initialize Gson variable

```
Gson g = new Gson();
```

a table of Exceptions appears:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
    at com.example.democtc.HelloApplication.main(HelloApplication.java:22)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application com.example.democtc.HelloApplication
```

Exceptions/Errors:

**InvocationTargetException**

**NoClassDefFoundError** (: com/google/gson/Gson)

**ClassNotFoundException** (: com/google/gson/Gson)

It seems like there is something wrong with the Gson class in library itself (?)
I also tried adding GSON jar from Github, but it didn't work for me. I'm newbie and probably do not understand Maven good enough, please, help me!

Comment: You've done a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, build is set correctly. Everything works, except Gson.

Comment: I have never used `<scope>compile</scope>`. What roles does that play?  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5

Comment: I've seen some people use it, so I added. Removing it changes nothing considering my problem, actually. Other options for "scope" are: test, runtime or provided. It seems like it indicates the role for particular dependency.

Comment: Please try `<version>2.8.8</version>`

Comment: I tried, but still it doesn't work. Trying to download 2.8.8 version (Libraries -> new from Maven etc.) it is inaccessible :/ (https://ibb.co/s681szh)